# How can I overload a constructor in Scala with a function as a parameter

Tags: scala, lambda, functional-programming, constructor-overloading

I am making a file searching program. This is contained in a "ParallelSearch" class. The signature is:

```
class ParallelSearch(condition: (Path, Int, String) => Boolean)
```

This is great and works. The user supplies a condition, that goes from a file path, a line number, and a string containing line content, to a Boolean. However, I would like to overload the constructor to allow the user to not specify file path or line number, and just search based on line contents. Like so:

```
def this(condition: String => Boolean) =
  {
    this((???): (Path, Int, String) => Boolean)
  }
```

What I'm not sure about is what to put where I have the `???` right now. I can answer any other questions that will make understanding easier. Any help is appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: You just create a new function that ignores the two first arguments and calls the provided function with the third one, something like: `this((_, _, text) => condition(text))`

Comment: I'll likely have 'Path' be empty and 'Int' be '-1'.

Comment: Luis that makes it compile thank you! I'll see if it does the job.

Comment: So what values will it have where the _ are? Is None? Or Nothing maybe?

Comment: You can also define them as `Options`, or use the `condition: String => Boolean` to be the first and main constructor, and the `condition: (Path, Int, String) => Boolean` as the alternative one.

Comment: @EzekielEmstad they have their corresponding types and values, you just ignore them.